# Not working wait_for in starting JBoss server via Ansible based on data from logs

Tags: ansible, jboss

I tried to start JBoss service via Ansible and use wai_for module to wait till the JBoss started. However, the JBoss service started, however, the wait_for still progressing until there is time out then hit error. Below is my code

```
- name: Get the contents of the last line from log
  command: "tail -n 1 /home/nityo/application.log"
  register: tail_output

- name: Create a variable with a meaningful name, just for clarity
  set_fact:
    last_line_of_the_log_file: "{{ tail_output.stdout }}"

- name: JBoss service starting
  service:
    name: "jboss.service"
    state: started
  become: yes
  become_user: root

- name:Wait for server started
  wait_for:
    path: "//home/nityo/application.log"
    search_regex: "{{ last_line_of_the_log_file }}\r(.*\r)*.*JBoss EAP.*started.*"
    timeout: 600
```

Besides that can we combine all thsi into 1 task rrather than having multiple task

Sample output log

```
2020-10-11 01:13:42,009 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBoss EAP 7.2 (WildFly Core) running in 100281ms - service to be running
2020-10-11 01:13:42,005 INFO  [org.jboss.as] processing data
2020-10-11 01:13:43,009 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBoss EAP 7.2 (WildFly Core) stopped in 100281ms - service to be stopped
-
-
-
-
-
-
-
2020-10-11 01:13:48,009 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBoss EAP 7.2 (WildFly Core) started in 100281ms - service to be started
```

Comment: Can you add an example `last_line_of_the_log_file`, does that line change? If it does, then chances of matching that in `wait_for` are remote.

Comment: Yea. The first task will get the last line. After that, server restarts. when server restart there are output being generasted roughtly takes 5 minutes but it depends. can be longer sometimes. So basically the output keep on changing

Answer (score 1):

It will never match in the last task, because you are searching for the last logfile line plus some extra stuff. You are using a variable in your regex, which contains a string that never matches if you add some other staff at the end of it.

So skip the first and second task and change your search_regex Parameter of the last task.

You could use the  ansible fact `ansible_date_time` (described in [Ansible date variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31323604/ansible-date-variable)) and use parts of date, time and/or epoch-seconds to build your regex via set_fact module. So your regex will match the logfile line with a timestamp not older then 10 minutes.

With `date` you could create a timestamp for a specific hour. The playbook could look like this:

```
---
- name: check logfile last 10 Minutes
  hosts:
  - localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: set now timestring
    command: 'date +"%Y-%m-%d %H"'
    register: date_now
  - name: set_now
    set_fact:
      now: "{{ date_now.stdout }}"
  - name: set 10 minutes ago timestring
    command: 'date +"%Y-%m-%d %H" -d "10 minutes ago"'
    register: date_10min_ago
  - name: set 10min_ago
    set_fact:
      ten_min_ago: "{{ date_10min_ago.stdout }}"
  - name: debug
    debug:
      msg: "({{ now }}|{{ ten_min_ago }}).*JBoss EAP.*started.*"
  - name: Wait for server started
    wait_for:
      path: "//home/nityo/application.log"
      search_regex: "({{ now }}|{{ ten_min_ago }}).*JBoss EAP.*started"
      timeout: 600
```

The Timestamps are totally different if the daliy limit is reached. In the middle of an hour, it seems superfluous. Debug-Output how the regex looks like this:

```
TASK [debug] **********************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "(2020-10-12 08|2020-10-12 08).*JBoss EAP.*started.*"
}
```

Comment: then how i can differentiate. as sometimes the server started twice a day. then how it can know it needs to look for the latest value. That the reason i come out to check last line then after that to restart the server and after that if matched that pattern then to stop as it means jboss server already started

Comment: you have some sample. i am not able to visualize what can be done

Answer (score 1):

What you are storing in `last_line_of_the_log_file` variable might not be getting matched at the default interval in which `wait_for` module checks by the time it reaches this task.

Checking service status by parsing a log file can be tricky. However I think the *cleanest way* will be to match the pattern `JBoss EAP.*started.*` in the log file. However for this to work reliably, it would be better to start with an empty log file before starting the service.

```yml
# Backup the log file with date/time stamp
- shell: cat /home/nityo/application.log >> /home/nityo/application-$(date %b-%d-%H-%M).log

# Empty the file contents before starting service
- command: truncate -s 0 /home/nityo/application.log

- wait_for:
    path: "/home/nityo/application.log"
    search_regex: "JBoss EAP.*started.*"
    timeout: 600
```

Parsing log files can be hit-or-miss if the logs generate differently in a given span of time. You can tweak the time, retries, and search pattern to get more consistent results.

**Update:**

It would be good to wait for some time to roll beyond the default lines (10) fetched by `tail` command, to avoid matching a previous startup. Then use `egrep`:

```yml
# Pause and wait for logs to roll beyond 10 lines fetched by 'tail'
- pause:
    seconds: 30

- shell: tail /home/nityo/application.log | grep -e "JBoss EAP.*started"
  register: file_tail
  until: file_tail is success
  # use appropriate values as per the rate of logging
  retries: 30
  delay: 20
```

Comment: i think i could not do the empty the file suggestions. I will give a try with the next solution you have provided

Comment: If file contents of the log file is a concern, it can be backed up and then emptied. Good luck with the other option!

Comment: i tried however, it stopped before the word started in JBoss EAP appears

Comment: within few seconds it stop. it didnt wait for it to execute fully. i am suspecting because we didnt give time input like from current time it should get the value from tail

Comment: There could be any `started` word in the log file. Can you try `until: "'started' in file_tail.stdout`?

Comment: yea. there are more than 1 started in the log file however, JBoss EAP 7.2 * started will be only once. and sometimes got few words appended after the started. as i observed, even through terminal i did tail grep jboss, it was still showing the previous value of started

Comment: your earlier answer is good, however, there should timestamp included to check after that time stamp shpould grep the words. I also figuring it out. saw soemthing egrep. checking on it

Comment: Adding logic to compare time stamps can make this Ansible playbook a little complex though. Good luck with that. Just `egrep` after waiting for some time might help (updated).

Comment: Thanks. AS I observed,  tail /home/nityo/application.log | grep "JBoss EAP", previously got data after i stop and then start and then stop and when starting time before the word "JBoss EAP" came, i did manually check in termianl the data was already there. Now i checked the data not there. wondering what happened

Comment: can help to add this in ur answer. cat /home/nityo/application.log | grep -e 'JBoss EAP.*started.*' | awk -F'[:, ]' '$2 >= 10 && $3 >= 41 && $4 >=42 && $5 >= 526 { print }'. before that need set the current execution time and date and then use it to compare. let me know if this is wrong approach

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222881/discussion-between-seshadri-c-and-salelne).