# How to print date in Ansible template module?

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

How to print the present date when the Ansible Jinja2 Template is run?

My Jinja2 template is

Today date is `date +%Y-%m-%d`

When I run the task it is simply copy pasting the same line, but I want todays date to be printed in the destination file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A built-in way of getting a date into a Jinja template is to use the `template_run_date` variable that's automatically available when using the [template module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/template_module.html).

For example a Jinja template file `my.conf.j2`

```
# My configuration file
# Updated on {{ template_run_date }}
```

Will render the date/time stamp of when the template was rendered.

Comment: Thank you for the input i used the {{ template_run_date }} it is also printing time not just date into Jinja template. Is there nay way to skip the timestamp?

Comment: Any specific reason for not wanting the timestamp?

Comment: My task specifies just date

Comment: You could consider using the other answers, though IMHO having date and timestamp makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

If [facts are gathered](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/gather_facts_module.html) it is also possible to use `{{ ansible_date_time.date }}`.

**Thanks to**

- [Ansible date variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31323604/)

Answer (score 1):

i dunno if i understand well your problem

but you just trap the date in a var and use the var in your template with "{{ date }}":

```
  tasks:
    - name: template {{ date }}
      template: your j2 file and destfile with {{date}} inside your j2
  vars:
    date: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'date +%Y-%m-%d') }}"
```